# Application of chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The equations $u=f(x,y),x=X(t),y=Y(t)$ define $u$ as a function of $t$, say $u=F(t)$.

Compute $F'(t)$ in terms of $t$ if, $$f(x,y)=\log [(1+e^{x^2})/(1+e^{y^2})] , X(t)=e , Y(t)^t=e^{-t}.$$

From the chain rule we have - $$F'(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}X'(t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}Y'(t).$$

Since $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are constant here and respectively equal to $e$ and $e^{-1}$, does this not mean that $F'(t)=0$?

Comment: Well, yes. Since $x=X(t)=e,y=Y(t)=e^{-1}$ are both constants, $f(x,y)=u$ is also a constant, i.e., $F(t):=u=f(x,y)$ is also a constant. Hence, $F^\prime(t)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x=X(t)=e,y=Y(t)=e^{-1}$ are both constants, $f(x,y)=u$ is also a constant, i.e., $F(t):=u=f(x,y)$ is also a constant. Hence, $F^\prime(t)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are constant with respect to $t$, then so is $F$. As $t$ changes, $X$ and $Y$ don't change, and therefore $f(X,Y)$ doesn't change either.